# Transform $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I was given the following task:

> Calculate the area B, described by the curve: $$\tag{x,y > 0}x^3+y^3-3xy=0$$

[image]

There are many ways to do this but my university told me to transform the curve into $$r(t); r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}; t = \frac{y}{x}$$

I've tried many things but did not get a closed form of $r(t)$:

$$x^3+y^3-3xy=0$$
$$x^3+y^3=3xy$$
$$x^2\cdot x+y^2\cdot y=3xy$$
$$x^2+y^2\cdot t=3y$$
$$\dfrac{y^2\cdot t}{y^2\cdot t}x^2+y^2\cdot t=3y$$
$$...$$

This keeps on going but I did not find a good result. I am very happy if someone could help me with transforming the curve into $r(t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tip**:

Replace $y$ with $tx$. You obtain
$$x^3(1+t^3)-3x^2t=0\iff \begin{cases}x=0\qquad\text{ or } \\x(1+t^3)=3t
\end{cases}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thank you! I will try to proceed

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to square the equation at some stage, because $r$ is expressed in terms of even powers of $x$ and $y$ and $t$ is homogeneous, while the original equation is not, and includes odd powers.

So I would go $$y=tx$$

$$r^2=x^2+y^2=x^2(1+t^2)$$

Substitute the first of these in the original equation $$(1+t^3)x^3=3tx^2$$

Now, either $x=0$ or $(1+t^3)x=3t$. Now square this to eliminate $x$ and get an expression in terms of $r^2$ and then you can take the square root confident that $r$ is positive.

Comment: I am stuck at "square this to eliminate x". Could you clarify?

Comment: @FinnEggers well you get $x^2$ in terms of $t$ and $r$ from the second equation - or you could just take the square root of the second equation to get $x$ directly.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is close to polar coordinates, with $t=\tan\theta$.

Hence plugging in the given equation,

$$r^3(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)-3r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta=0$$

or

$$r=\frac{3\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta}=\frac{3\dfrac1{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\dfrac t{\sqrt{t^2+1}}}{\dfrac1{(\sqrt{t^2+1})^3}+\dfrac{t^3}{(\sqrt{t^2+1})^3}}=3t\frac{\sqrt{t^2+1}}{t^3+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates with $$x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta , t=\tan \theta$$

Results in $$ r(1+t^3)-3t\sqrt {1+t^2}=0$$
You can solve for $r$ as a function of $t$